# java 9 modules, NoClassDefFoundError: java.sql.Date

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, java-9

I tried running our java 8 gradle project with java 9, since we are looking to migrate to it. However, when executing a unit test I get a

`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.sql.Date` exception

thrown by `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.DateDeserializers`

Looks like this in code:

```
static {
    Class<?>[] numberTypes = new Class<?>[] {
        ...
        java.sql.Date.class,
        ...
    };
    ...
}
```

I have looked around on the internet, and apparently, if you want to avoid making a `module-info.java` file for every module, you have to add the parameter `--add-modules java.sql`.

I am using intellij, and have added the parameter to the javac arguments in `File>Settings>Build,Execution,Deployment>Compiler>Java Compiler` and also in the run config as VM option, but I still get an exception.

Is there an easier way to do this, or what am I doing wrong?
Thanks

edit:
IntelliJ Version:

```
IntelliJ IDEA 2018.1.5 (Community Edition)
Build #IC-181.5281.24, built on June 12, 2018
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1136-b39 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Windows 10 10.0
```

Comment: what's your intelliJ version and can you show us your complete execution configurations form intelliJ?

Comment: If you don't create a `module-info.java`, all Java SE modules, _java.sql_ among them, will be available at run time, so you don't need `--add-modules`. Something else must be wrong.

Comment: Can you paste in some of the stack trace to help diagnose this? One possible reason is that there is a custom class loader in the picture that is delegating to the boot loader (the java.sql module is mapped to the platform class loader). Another reason is that you've migrated to modules and missed `requires java.sql` (but that doesn't explain how the code was compiled).

Comment: If you created module-info.java, as you should going forward, just add "requires java.sql;"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue fixed itself after I removed the jdk9 and re-added it.